# Increasing JLabel size over time

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

Is it possible to make a JLabel increase in size over time? I tried using thread.sleep() in a for loop but it didn't work properly. It just waited for n seconds and then pasted the JLabel in.

The code I used:

```
    try {
         for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
             label.setBounds(x, y, 125+(i*20), 125+(i*20));
             Thread.sleep(1000);
         }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If label doesnt have background you can´t see changes when you change her size with setBounds. If that´s the case you may want to change font size as well.

Comment: @Andrej It had an icon set to it, it kinda just skips from not being there to being at it's full size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use javax.swing.Timer

Example:

```
//1000 is the delay of each tick
 timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
             if(i == 2)
             {
                 timer.stop();
             }

            label.setBounds(71, 194, 125+(i*20), 125+(i*20));
             i++;
         }
      });
 timer.start();
```

Comment: That's perfect thank you, is it possible to get this action to stop once the counter i passes a certain threshold?

Comment: @Yopper You can do that by creating instance of Timer object and calling stop() method. I edited my answer.